onQueryStarted RTK Query triggers twice
Context
I have getGroupList API. It's called in 3 screens with different parameters. So I'm creating 3 cache entries. It's a requirement.
On the other hand, I have the deleteGroupUser API basically deletes a user from a group. So the easy path is to use invalidateTags pointing to getGroupList Tag but it will trigger 3 API requests. So I'm trying to avoid that.
At this point is when onQueryStarted arrives and I'm using it to update optimistically the cache. But the main issue I found it is getting triggered twice and that ruins what I want to achieve.
Code
APIs definition
getGroupList: builder.query<
        BaseListResponseFor<IGroup>,
        GroupsQueryParams
      >({
        query: (params) => ({
          url: 'api/v1/groups',
          method: APIMethods.GET,
          params,
        }),
        serializeQueryArgs: ({
          queryArgs,
          endpointDefinition,
          endpointName,
        }) => {
          const { user_id, role } = queryArgs;
          return defaultSerializeQueryArgs({
            endpointName,
            queryArgs: { user_id, role },
            endpointDefinition,
          });
        },
        providesTags: (result) =>
          tagsProvider<IGroup>(result, GROUPS_CACHE_TAGS.GroupList),
        transformResponse(response) {
          return response.data;
        },
        merge: (currentCache, responseData) => {
                       (...)
        },
      }),

deleteGroupUser: builder.mutation<
      BaseDeleteResponse,
      { groupId?: number; groupUserId: number }
    >({
      query: ({ groupUserId }) => ({
        url: `api/v1/group_users/${groupUserId}`,
        method: APIMethods.DELETE,
      }),
      onQueryStarted: (
        { groupUserId, groupId },
        { dispatch, queryFulfilled }
      ) => {
        const myGroupsPatch = dispatch(
          groupsApi.util.updateQueryData(
            'getGroupList',
            {
              user_id: store?.getState()?.auth?.userId,
            },
            (draft) => {
              const index = draft.items.findIndex(
                (group) => group?.own_group_user?.id === groupUserId
              );
              if (index >= 0) draft.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
          )
        );
        queryFulfilled.catch(myGroupsPatch.undo);

        const manageGroupsPatch = dispatch(
          groupsApi.util.updateQueryData(
            'getGroupList',
            {
              role: GroupUserRole.Owner,
              user_id: store?.getState()?.auth?.userId,
            },
            (draft) => {
              const index = draft.items.findIndex(
                (group) => group?.own_group_user?.id === groupUserId
              );
              if (index >= 0) draft.items.splice(index, 1);

              const groupIndex = draft.items.findIndex(
                (group) => group?.id === groupId
              );
              if (groupIndex >= 0) {

                draft.items[groupIndex].group_users_count -= 1; <---- HERE
              }
            }
          )
        );
        queryFulfilled.catch(manageGroupsPatch.undo);

      },
      invalidatesTags: () => [
        GROUPS_CACHE_TAGS.Group,
        GROUPS_CACHE_TAGS.GroupUserList,
      ],
    }),

APIs calls
** GroupsManageScreen.tsx **
 const { data, refetch } = useGetGroupListQuery({
    page,
    user_id: userId,
    keyword: debouncedQuery,
    role: GroupUserRole.Owner,
  });

** GroupsHomeScreen.tsx **
const debouncedQuery = useDebounce(searchBoxValue, 1000)[0];
  const { data, refetch } = useGetGroupListQuery(
    {
      page,
      user_id: userId,
      keyword: debouncedQuery,
    },
    { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true }
  );

** GroupsDiscoverScreen.tsx **
const { data, refetch } = useGetGroupListQuery(
    {
      page,
      user_id: userId,
      keyword: debouncedQuery,
      role: GroupUserRole.NotMember,
    },
    { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true }
  );

GroupMembersScreen.tsx
  const [deleteGroupUser] = useDeleteGroupUserMutation();

  const onRemoveGroupUser = useCallback(
    async (userId: number) =>
      await deleteGroupUser({
        groupUserId: userId,
        groupId: groupData?.id,
      }).then(() =>
        setToast({
          render: () => <Toast text={'User removed'} display />,
        })
      ),
    [deleteGroupUser, groupData?.id, setToast]
  );

Goal
Update the user counting by reducing it by one 'cause I'm removing only one user.
Actual Result
So in the case I have 10 users result should be 9 but I'm getting 8 as result of onQueryStarted 'cause it's getting called twice

Where are you initiating the deleteGroupUser endpoint? Are you doing this in a useEffect hook somewhere and just happen to be rendering the app into a React.StrictMode component? Do you have multiple groups cached that have the same group id such that calling the mutation endpoint removes more than you want? Please [edit] to clarify the issue and provide a complete and relevant [mcve]. I also can't help but think that using cache tags more efficiently could likely help here, but your description of their use was unclear.

I'm not using useEffect at all. Well if you check on each updateQueryData is pointing to different cache keys. So myGroupsPatch & mangeGroupsPatch are getting different cache entries. Well regarding Tags I'm trying to avoid using it only "on this case" 'cause it will trigger 3 API requests at the same time. So let's say 1000 user requests should be multiplied by 3 the result is not the best performance. So updating that value could avoid unnecessary API calls.

Queries are already cached separately, based on their args... are you doing something custom over the default behavior here that somehow breaks this abstraction? You haven't shared what your query endpoints do, so it's difficult to just take your word that "3 API requests" happen at the same time with regards to any single triggering "action". There is why a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with is important and helpful.

Ok let me add more code
